# my if statement wont work with random number

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a natural disaster sequance for my game and using the Math.random to simulate variants of an outbreak. So the problem is at the very bottom of my code theres an if statement that should detect if the number hits 0 but it dosent work for some reason. I tried using parseInt() but it still dident work. I'm probaly doing something obveous wrong. Thank you for reading.

```js
var start = document.getElementById("startbtn");
var waterOut = document.getElementById("waterOut");

start.addEventListener("click", disaster1);

function disaster1() {
  //fire
  var fireDisaster = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var water = 1000;
  setInterval(function() {
    waterOut.innerHTML = "Water: " + water;
    
  }, 1);
  
  var waterbtn = document.getElementById("putFireOutbtn");
  var fireCount = document.getElementById("fireCount");
  var fireCountNumber = fireCount;

  fireCount.innerHTML = "Fire: " + fireDisaster;
  alert("Theres a wild fire! Use your water to put it out!");

  if (fireDisaster >= 1) {
    waterbtn.style.width = "100px";
    waterbtn.style.height = "100px";
    waterbtn.style.left = "50%";
    waterbtn.addEventListener("click", putOutFire);

    function putOutFire() {
      if (water >= 1) {
        water -= 1;
        fireDisaster -= 1;
        console.log(fireDisaster);
      }
      fireCount.innerHTML = "Fire: " + fireDisaster;
    }
  }

  if (fireDisaster == 0) {
    waterbtn.style.width = "0px";
    waterbtn.style.height = "0px";
    waterbtn.style.left = "1500px";
    alert("You put out the fire!");
    fireCount.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="waterOut"></p>
<p id="fireCount"></p>
<button id="startbtn">start</button>
<button id="putFireOutbtn">put out the fire!</button>
```

Comment: You always add `1`. How could it ever be zero?

Comment: `var fireCountNumber = fireCount.value;` - Isn't `fireCount` a reference to a `<p>` element?  Those don't have a "value".

Comment: try using console.log(fireDisaster); and check the results, maybe there is a decimal <= 1 on this number.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice the second `if` statement was referencing something else. So many wrong.

Comment: I tried using the console.log(fireDisaster) and found that the number stayed the same as it was outputed. Even when it hit 0 the other if statement that should have triggered the end of the disaster dident trigger.

Comment: Even if you get proper value, you will get "Fire: number" and not a number itself

Comment: @LiamSperry, try `console.log(fireCountNumber )`, you will see the problem

Comment: thank you i fixed my code so that the last if statement only relies on fireDisaster. But the problem still stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're checking `fireDisaster` only once when the disaster hits.  You want to check it continuously as you put water on the fire, so add that code to the `putOutFire` function:

```
function putOutFire() {
    if (water >= 1) {
        water -= 1;
        fireDisaster -= 1;
        console.log(fireDisaster);
    }
    fireCount.innerHTML = "Fire: " + fireDisaster;
    if (fireDisaster == 0) {
        waterbtn.style.width = "0px";
        waterbtn.style.height = "0px";
        waterbtn.style.left = "1500px";
        alert("You put out the fire!");
        fireCount.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really confusing for me but such a big step in my program! Again thank you!